Low Ramsey Reset test p-value (LinReg)
I'm working on my final project for an Introductory econometrics course. I am modeling used Porsche 911 prices using simple linear regression in python. What is bothering is the low p-value of the RESET test even though I've tried using interaction terms (Mileage x Years), second powers (Mileage^2) etc. Lowest RESET p-value and highest R^2 comes out if I use log-lin model with logarithm of the Y variable (price) so that seems to be the best fit for now. Any ideas for improvement? Is RESET test really that of a big deal?
Here's the code just in case:
Y = df["log_price"]
X = df[["IS911", "IS964", "IS993", "IS996", "IS997", "IS991", "Special", "S", "RS", "Turbo", "GT", "Targa", "Cabriolet", "Automat", "Power", "Mileage", "CylCap"]]
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model5= sm.OLS(Y, X).fit()
print(model5.summary())

from statsmodels.stats.diagnostic import linear_reset
reset_test = linear_reset(model5, power=3)
print("P-hodnota:", reset_test.pvalue)

Returns: 
R^2 = 0.857 (Adj. R^2 = 0.856) 
all variables are statistically significant 
RESET p-value: 0.00022819301719425838 
Variables used: 
Dummy variables: IS911, IS964, IS993, IS996, IS997, IS991, Special, S, RS, Turbo,GT, Targa, Cabriolet, Automat (1 if true, 0 if not)
Continuous variables: Power, Mileage, CylCap

Welcome to Cross Validated! Don't you kind of know your model is not the correct model? There is a mantra in statistics: "all models are wrong, but some are useful." $//$ What did your class teach as the action to take based on the RESET test results? $//$ A more complete answer to how to make modeling decisions is the entirety of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies book.

What's your sample size? // are any of the models very rare?
